# How to change the privileges of a table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, sql-grant

I try to grant specific privileges to my table "MEMBERS" in postgresql but nothing changes. More specifically I do this (through pgadmin console):

```
    CREATE DATABASE login;
    CREATE USER loginUser WITH PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    CREATE TABLE members (
     id serial NOT NULL,
     username varchar(30) NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
    )

    ALTER USER loginuser WITH SUPERUSER;
    ALTER TABLE members OWNER TO loginuser;

    GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON members TO loginuser;
```

The query is returned successfully but when I check the table's privileges through the pgadmin gui all of them are selected.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with "*all of them are selected*". You granted all privileges so what exactly do you expect? And what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I didn't grant all privileges. What are you talking about?  There are still TRUNCATE, REFERECES, DROP, TRIGGER privileges. Even if I execute this query:  GRANT SELECT  ON members TO loginuser; all the privileges are selected instead only of SELECT privilege.

Comment: But `loginuser` is the _owner_ of the table so that role *does* have all privileges.

Comment: I see your point now. Is there a way to change the privileges of the owner of an owner?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Worse than that: "loginuser" is a superuser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a table's owner has full privileges on it. If you want "loginuser" to have only select, update, insert, and delete privileges, you would normally revoke all privileges first, then grant just those four.

```
revoke all on members from loginuser;
grant select, update, insert, delete on members to loginuser;
```

This will appear to work for you, but it really won't. A database superuser *can* revoke privileges from a table's owner.  But you've made "loginuser" a superuser. Whatever privileges you revoke, "loginuser" can just grant to herself.

You need to think more carefully about what you're trying to accomplish here.